# Extract chart data in powerpoint to clipboard (VBA-code almost working)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I found a solution to this ([Retrieve excel chart data from powerpoint slide (programmatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36661499/retrieve-excel-chart-data-from-powerpoint-slide-programmatically)), but I cannot get it to work 100%. After I execute the VBA, I get the message saying "successfully copied to clipboard", but there is nothing in the clipboard.

Is this VBA working for anyone?

This is the VBA code:

```
    Sub RipChartValues()
Dim cht As PowerPoint.Chart
Dim seriesIndex As Long
Dim labels As Variant
Dim values As Variant
Dim name As String
Dim buffer As String
Dim objData As Object

Set cht = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Parent.Shapes(ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.name).Chart

With cht
    For seriesIndex = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count
    name = .SeriesCollection(seriesIndex).name
    labels = .SeriesCollection(seriesIndex).XValues
    values = .SeriesCollection(seriesIndex).values

    If seriesIndex = 1 Then buffer = vbTab & Join(labels, vbTab) & vbCrLf
    buffer = buffer & (name & vbTab & Join(values, vbTab) & vbCrLf)
    Next

End With

On Error Resume Next
' Rory's late bind example
' this is a late bound MSForms.DataObject
Set objData = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

' copy current cell formula to clipboard
With objData
    .SetText buffer
    .PutInClipboard
    MsgBox "Data extracted to clipboard!", vbOKOnly, "Success"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need the data in the clipboard? I've always found it more reliable and less confusing to put the data into a VBA array, and deal with it that way.

Comment: Not at all! I am just trying to figure a way out, but I'm not there yet where I can code VBA myself. I found this snipped online while searching. Do you mind sharing the VBA you use?

Comment: Where do you want the data to end up? A worksheet? I could give you some code that will extract the data, put it into the columns of a worksheet, with some information at the top (like presentation path and name, slide number, chart name or number).

Comment: A worksheet would be great, thanks! I am adding old chart data into a new presentation, so I essentially only have to paste the old info (values and labels) into a new chart - but having it in another worksheet I can just copy it from there.

Comment: Rather than a worksheet, I provided PowerPoint code that spits out data into an Excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use the clipboard, which can be problematic. Instead, I looped through the PowerPoint chart, and dumped the X and Y values and series name into a new Excel worksheet.

Here's the code:

```
Sub ExtractChartValues()
  '' Set reference to Microsoft Excel Object Library
  
  ' find running Excel application
  Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
  On Error Resume Next
  Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
  On Error GoTo 0
  If xlApp Is Nothing Then
    ' Excel not running, so start it up
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True
  End If
  
  ' worksheet to output chart data
  Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
  Set ws = xlApp.Workbooks.Add.Worksheets(1)

  Dim cht As PowerPoint.Chart
  Set cht = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Parent.Shapes _
      (ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Name).Chart
  Dim ixSeries As Long
  ' loop through series in chart
  For ixSeries = 1 To cht.SeriesCollection.Count
    Dim srs As Series
    Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection(ixSeries)
    Dim SrsName As String
    SrsName = srs.name
    Dim SrsXVals As Variant
    SrsXVals = srs.XValues
    Dim SrsYVals As Variant
    SrsYVals = srs.values
    ' output: pair of columns for each series
    '         first column: blank first row, X values below
    '         second column: name in first row, Y values below
    ws.Cells(1, ixSeries * 2).Value = SrsName
    ws.Cells(2, ixSeries * 2 - 1).Resize(UBound(SrsXVals) + 1 - LBound(SrsXVals)).Value = _
        xlApp.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SrsXVals)
    ws.Cells(2, ixSeries * 2).Resize(UBound(SrsYVals) + 1 - LBound(SrsYVals)).Value = _
        xlApp.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SrsYVals)
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an alternative approach. The PowerPoint chart stores its data in something called a ChartData object, and this is basically comprised of an Excel workbook, embedded in the slide with the chart.

Here's some PowerPoint VBA code that saves the workbook, so you can simply open it in Excel:

```
Sub ExportChartDataSheet()
  Dim cht As PowerPoint.Chart
  Set cht = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Parent.Shapes _
      (ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.name).Chart
  Dim chtdat As ChartData
  Set chtdat = cht.ChartData
  Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
  Set wb = chtdat.Workbook
  Dim IsVisible As Boolean
  IsVisible = wb.Windows(1).Visible
  If Not IsVisible Then
    wb.Windows(1).Visible = True
  End If
  Dim sFileName As String
  sFileName = Left$(ActivePresentation.FullName, InStrRev(ActivePresentation.FullName, ".") - 1) _
      & "_" & ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.name & "_Output.xlsx"
  wb.SaveAs sFileName, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
  wb.Windows(1).Visible = IsVisible
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution, thanks! Once I try to run the VBA, I get "User-defined type not defined" error, pointing towards (Dim)"wb As Workbook". I tried Googling for a solution, but did not find anything relevant. Is this script working for you?

I'm on MacOS, Powerpoint 16.22.

Comment: Set a reference to the Excel object model. In the VB Editor, go to Tools menu > References, and scroll down to Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library, check the box, and click OK.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! I managed to get past the first error, but now I get a different error:

When selecting a single chart in the presentation, I get the error "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch", pointing towards "Set wb = chtdat.Workbook".

While I select all slides, I get this error:
Run-time error '.2147188160 (80048240)': Selection (unknown member: invalid request. This view does not support selection), pointing towards "Set cht = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Parent.Shapes _
                (ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Name).Chart"

Comment: How did you get around the first error? Did you set a reference? It might also be better to `Dim wb As Excel.Workbook`.

Comment: The code doesn't work on all slides, it only works on the selected chart on one slide. There's hardly any error checking, so if you haven't selected a shape, or if the shape isn't a chart, there's an error. If you want to export all data for all charts, you'll have to loop through all slides, then through all shapes on each slide, test whether it's a chart, then make sure you're using a unique file name for the exported data. Or maybe adapt the code in my other answer, so it extracts the data for each chart onto a new sheet of the workbook.